# NAS configuration and Intel Celeron better than Pentium?

Tags: cpu, nas

While choosing a NAS, I came across the Synology DS918+ and WD PR4100. Synology DS918+ uses [Intel Celeron J3455](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95594/intel-celeron-processor-j3455-2m-cache-up-to-2-3-ghz.html), and WD PR4100 uses [Intel Pentium N3710](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91830/intel-pentium-processor-n3710-2m-cache-up-to-2-56-ghz.html). Celeron is 1.5GHz burst to 2.3, while Pentium is 1.6 burst to 2.56. Both are quad core. This is [their comparison](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=95594,91830).

While it is common from the numbers and from the model to think Pentium is better than Celeron, the numbers tell otherwise. The [benchmark shows that Celeron may be 50% better performance than the Pentium](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Pentium-N3710-vs-Intel-Celeron-J3455/m141841vsm200485).  Both are released in 2016, so we are not comparing a Celeron in 2016 to a Pentium in 2009.  What is this about?

Comment: There are lots of options in the Synology line, and they provide different CPUs for different usecases.  I have had great experiences with Synology over the years, so you may want to check out other models in '18 lineup. Also consider, most of the time, CPU isn't the most important thing to consider when buying a NAS. what do you expect to do with it? will it include VMs, Docker hosting, or Video Transcoding?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that both the Celeron and the Pentium lines go back decades. I believe the first  celeron I ever saw was running Windows ME (though its a hazy memory so take it for what its worth). They've always had a different performance profile than the Pentiums they pair with, but I'd take a modern Celeron over the first Core2 I bought (or my disastrous dalliance with a Pentium-D).

Answer (score 2):

You can see on Intel ARK (your comparison link) that Celeron has higher TDP: 10 W for Celeron J3455 vs. 6 W for Pentium N3710. In layman's terms this means that this particular Celeron was designed to consume and dissipate higher amount of power than this particular Pentium. This will obviously result in slightly higher power consumption, but larger power budget also allows for better performance.

Both processors have the same number of similar cores, but they must have been designed to stay within their different power budgets when under full load. In [this benchmark comparison](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-Celeron-J3455-vs-Intel-Pentium-N3710/2875vs2730) you can see that both CPUs have similar single core performance. When only a single core is under load, CPU has some power headroom, so the core can actually boost to advertised frequency. When more cores are in use, CPU hits the power limit and is more conservative in its frequency management. N3710's TDP is lower, hence it's less performant under high load.

Comment: In a whole year, Celeron costs $0.73 more in energy cost? It seems like energy is not too costly recently

Comment: Keep in mind that typical desktop CPUs have TDP around 65 W, sometimes more for high-performance units, and they are not even the most power-hungry PC components (graphics cards are). A few years ago about 150 W wasn't unusual. Even modern laptop CPUs usually have TDP around 15 W. These two CPUs are ultra low power units.